# Gatsby version 5 build failed on Cloudflare worker

Tags: reactjs, dockerfile, gatsby, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I upgraded Gatsby from v4 to v5, it is hosted on Cloudflare worker. When it builds it gives a permission error, maybe related to Dockerfile or it maybe related to cache. Cloudflare doesnt have option to clear cache when deploy. How do i fix the build error?

Below is the build error

```
   13:35:15.682   
    13:35:15.682      - index.js:141 
    13:35:15.682        [adapters]/[p-map]/index.js:141:20
    13:35:15.682      
    13:35:15.682      - Caused By: NestedError: Cannot create directory `/opt/build/cache/cwd/.cache
    13:35:15.682        `: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/build/cache'
    13:35:15.682      
    13:35:15.683      - fs.js:61 
    13:35:15.683        [adapters]/[cp-file]/fs.js:61:8
    13:35:15.683      
    13:35:15.683      - index.js:15 cpFileAsync
    13:35:15.683        [adapters]/[cp-file]/index.js:15:2
    13:35:15.683      
    13:35:15.683      - index.js:269 pMap.concurrency.concurrency
    13:35:15.683        [adapters]/[cpy]/index.js:269:6
    13:35:15.684      
    13:35:15.684      - index.js:141 
    13:35:15.684        [adapters]/[p-map]/index.js:141:20
    13:35:15.684      
    13:35:15.684      - Caused By: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/build/cache'
    13:35:15.684      
    13:35:15.684    
    13:35:15.684    
    13:35:15.685    
    13:35:15.685    Pages
    13:35:15.685    
    13:35:15.685    ┌ src/template/authorTemplate.js
    13:35:15.685    │ ├   /blog/author/deniz-mustafa/
    13:35:15.685    │ └   ...19 more pages available
    13:35:15.685    ├ src/template/blogTemplate.js
    13:35:15.685    │ ├   /blog/how-to-select-a-third-party-risk-management-framework/
    13:35:15.685    │ └   ...353 more pages available
    13:35:15.686    ├ src/template/categoryTemplate.js
    13:35:15.686    │ ├   /blog/category/attack-surface-management/
    13:35:15.686    │ └   ...10 more pages available
    13:35:15.686    ├ src/template/industryTemplate.js
    13:35:15.687    │ ├   /education/
    13:35:15.687    │ └   ...5 more pages available
    13:35:15.687    ├ src/template/featuresTemplate.js
    13:35:15.687    │ ├   /alerts/
    13:35:15.688    │ └   ...6 more pages available
    13:35:15.688    ├ src/pages/404.js
    13:35:15.688    │ ├   /404/
    13:35:15.688    │ └   /404.html
    13:35:15.689    ├ src/pages/about.js
    13:35:15.689    │ └   /about/
    13:35:15.689    ├ src/pages/authors.js
    13:35:15.689    │ └   /authors/
    13:35:15.690    ├ src/pages/blog.js
    13:35:15.690    │ └   /blog/
    13:35:15.690    ├ src/pages/contact.js
    13:35:15.690    │ └   /contact/
    13:35:15.690    ├ src/pages/cookie-policy.js
    13:35:15.691    │ └   /cookie-policy/
    13:35:15.691    ├ src/pages/ebooks.js
    13:35:15.691    │ └   /ebooks/
    13:35:15.691    ├ src/pages/glossary.js
    13:35:15.691    │ └   /glossary/
    13:35:15.691    ├ src/pages/index.js
    13:35:15.692    │ └   /
    13:35:15.692    ├ src/pages/news.js
    13:35:15.692    │ └   /news/
    13:35:15.692    ├ src/pages/pricing.js
    13:35:15.692    │ └   /pricing/
    13:35:15.692    ├ src/pages/privacy-policy.js
    13:35:15.692    │ └   /privacy-policy/
    13:35:15.693    ├ src/pages/shakhsiyah.js
    13:35:15.693    │ └   /shakhsiyah/
    13:35:15.693    ├ src/pages/terms-of-use.js
    13:35:15.693    │ └   /terms-of-use/
    13:35:15.693    ├ src/pages/thank-you.js
    13:35:15.693    │ └   /thank-you/
    13:35:15.693    ├ src/pages/why-securiwiser.js
    13:35:15.694    │ └   /why-securiwiser/
    13:35:15.694    ├ src/pages/news/authors.js
    13:35:15.694    │ └   /news/authors/
    13:35:15.694    ├ src/pages/ebook/education/index.js
    13:35:15.694    │ └   /ebook/education/
    13:35:15.694    ├ src/pages/ebook/finance/index.js
    13:35:15.695    │ └   /ebook/finance/
    13:35:15.695    ├ src/pages/ebook/government/index.js
    13:35:15.695    │ └   /ebook/government/
    13:35:15.695    ├ src/pages/ebook/health/index.js
    13:35:15.695    │ └   /ebook/health/
    13:35:15.695    ├ src/pages/ebook/retail/index.js
    13:35:15.696    │ └   /ebook/retail/
    13:35:15.696    └ src/pages/ebook/technology/index.js
    13:35:15.696      └   /ebook/technology/
    13:35:15.696    
    13:35:15.696      ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
    13:35:15.696      │                                                                │
    13:35:15.696      │   (SSG) Generated at build time                                │
    13:35:15.697      │ D (DSG) Deferred static generation - page generated at runtime │
    13:35:15.697      │ ∞ (SSR) Server-side renders at runtime (uses getServerData)    │
    13:35:15.697      │ λ (Function) Gatsby function                                   │
    13:35:15.697      │                                                                │
    13:35:15.697      ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
    13:35:15.697    
    13:35:16.129    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
    13:35:17.655    Failed: error occurred while running build command
    13:35:17.655    Note: Not all logs could be displayed, click "Download log" to view more
```

The Dockerfile is below

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine AS deploy
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY --from=build /app/public .
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

File package.json

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "overrides": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@builder.io/partytown": "^0.7.1",
    "@fontsource/sora": "^4.5.3",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "gatsby": "^5.13.0-next.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls": "^5.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-complex-sitemap-tree": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-facebook-pixel": "^1.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^4.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "4.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies": "^2.0.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag": "^5.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^5.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-mailchimp": "^5.2.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "4.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "7.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^6.10.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "5.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.6.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "4.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-utils": "^3.18.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "4.10",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^5.11.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.11.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mdast-util-to-nlcst": "^5.2.1",
    "netlify-cms-app": "^2.15.59",
    "npm": "^8.1.4",
    "plyr-react": "^3.2.1",
    "preact": "^10.6.4",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.19",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "radium": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-awesome-reveal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.9",
    "react-share": "^4.4.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2": "^1.1.26",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "preload-fonts": "gatsby-preload-fonts",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1",
    "check-npm-version": "npm -v | grep -E '^7|^8|^9|^10' || (echo 'NPM version 7+ required' && exit 1)"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem? I am facing the same one...